# How can i get all user from Oracle Internet Directory using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, oid

How can i get all user from Oracle Internet Directory using vbscript?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, OID is just another LDAP service so I assume it can be queried using code similar to this:

```
Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set cmd =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

cmd.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
cmd.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE 

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM 'LDAP://dc=test,dc=com' WHERE objectCategory='user'"
Set rec = cmd.Execute

rec.MoveFirst
Do Until rec.EOF
    Wscript.Echo rec.Fields("Name").Value
    rec.MoveNext
Loop
```

But changing `LDAP://dc=test,dc=com` to what you need to use to bind to it properly.

Comment: How about to retrieve their password? do I need to change the Name to userpassword and also the objectCategory?

Comment: The `objectCategory` would stay the same for other user properties, but I'd assume that you won't be able to get out the password since that would be insecure. You might be able to change the password using something like `SetPassword` though.

Comment: the OID user password attribute is called UserPassword.